# Run Commands on remote Servers from a Webapplication

Tags: python

I have the following problem: I have to run commands on remote servers from within a web application (play), but from the web server I have no ssh access to the remote servers. The only thing I have is, that the remote servers have access to the web server via http(s).

My idea was to create a python daemon, that polls a URL which returns the requested commands via JSON.

Is that a good idea? Is there a framework that could help here on the clients?

BR Rene

Comment: What exactly do you need to do on the remote server? Execute arbitrary shell commands? Execute one specific shell command?

Comment: Execute arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: Seems like a Bad Idea. If you must do this, at least allow only a restricted set of commands (inside a chroot jail would be nice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My idea was to create a python daemon, that polls a URL which returns
>   the requested commands via JSON.

This is essentially a message broker. So instead of writing one yourself, use any of the available message brokers such as [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) that have bindings for Java and whatever language you are going to run on the target server.

From your web server, dispatch a message to the broker. This would trigger a worker on the target server to "wake up" and do some task. You can then optionally fetch the result across the message broker as well, or write it to some common store (like update some k/v store, or write to a common database).

Comment: That was initially also my idea, but I cannot install a new message broker server. I think the only solution I have is the one I mentioned.

Comment: It doesn't need to be on a dedicated machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do remote calls with **pyro**, you can call remote python object. Python Remote Objects is a distributed object system written entirely in Python, and for use in Python only. It is small, simple and free. Check it here: [pyro](http://pyro.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Unfortunately no port is open to the remote servers. I just jave http(s) connections from the remote servers to the web server.